How can i plot a scichart with time on X axis in React js using timestamp
As i try to plot time on X axis in scichart graph in React js i am getting wrong date and time. I use timestamp to plot the X axis , i need only the time HH:MM:SS format not the date.
// plotLine is array of objects with x and y.
// x is array of timestamp and y is array of y values.
        startDate = new Date(plotLine.x[0]).getTime();   
        setXStart(startDate)    
        const totalPoints = plotLine.y.length;  
        const xValues = Array.from({ length: totalPoints }, (_, i) => new    Date(plotLine.x[i]).getTime());  
        endDate=new Date(plotLine.x[plotLine.x.length - 1]).getTime(); 
        setXEnd(endDate);  
        xyDataSeriesCollection[line.Key]?.appendRange(xValues, plotLine.y);  

// This is how i initialised the X axis
const xAxis = new DateTimeNumericAxis(wasmContext, {
growBy: new NumberRange(0.1, 0.1), 
defaultXStep: .1, 
labelProvider: new SmartDateLabelProvider(), 
axisAlignment: EAxisAlignment.Bottom, 
autoRange: EAutoRange.Never, 
drawMajorGridLines: false,
drawMinorGridLines: false,
})             
sciChartSurface.xAxes.add(xAxis);

I am getting date and time on the x axis but is incorrect.
